# SparkSQL - The correlated scalar subquery can only contain equality predicates

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I would like to execute the following query with Spark SQL 2.0

```
SELECT
a.id as id,
(SELECT SUM(b.points) 
  FROM tableB b 
  WHERE b.id = a.id AND b.date <= a.date) AS points
FROM tableA a
```

but I get the following error

`The correlated scalar subquery can only contain equality predicates`.

Any idea how can I rewrite the query or use operations between the two dataframes tableA and tableB to make it working?

Comment: is there a pattern to how b.date is later than a.date? is it always a day, month or year more? if so, we might be able to add that pattern to the comparison, e.g.: a.date +1 day = b.date

Comment: good comment! but unfortunately not, b.date can be whatever date/time previous than a.date.

Comment: next question: do you really need b.date <= a.date? Doesn't a.id = b.id suffice? or is there really more than one pair of matching ids? If yes, is there another unique comparison between a and b that can be made?

Comment: Scroll to the bottom of: https://dwgeek.com/spark-sql-correlated-subquery-and-usage-restrictions.html/

Answer (score 3):

```
select a.id as id, 
sum(b.points) as points 
from a, b 
where a.id = b.id 
and b.date <= a.date 
group by a.id 
;
```

Skip the sub-select and `group by` id to ensure a one to one relationship between ids and the sum of b's points column.

Here's a 'down and dirty' example which I used:

```
select * from a ;

id|date
1|2017-01-22 17:59:49
2|2017-01-22 18:00:00
3|2017-01-22 18:00:05
4|2017-01-22 18:00:11
5|2017-01-22 18:00:15

select * from b ;
id|points|date
1|12|2017-01-21 18:03:20
3|25|2017-01-21 18:03:37
5|17|2017-01-21 18:03:55
2|-1|2017-01-22 18:04:27
4|-4|2017-01-22 18:04:35
5|400|2017-01-20 18:17:31
5|-1000|2017-01-23 18:18:36
```

Notice that b has three entries of id = 5, two before a.date and one after.

```
select a.id, sum(b.points) as points from a, b where a.id = b.id and b.date <= a.date group by a.id ;
1|12
3|25
5|417
```

I also confirmed "group by" is supported: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#supported-hive-features